# async await not waiting for object to fill axios.get

Tags: javascript, node.js, async-await, axios

I have an object called `move_dict` and am using the method `get_learned_by_pokemon()` to fill it. In `getPokes()` I call the `get_learned_by_pokemon()` and expect `move_dict` to be filled. However it is empty.

```
function move(){
    let move_dict = {}
    let db_data = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync('pokes.json', 'utf8'));
    async function get_learned_by_pokemon(curr_move, move_dict, current_poke){
        response = await axios.get('https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/move/'.concat(curr_move))

        let learned_by_pokemons = []
        for (let k = 0; k < response.data.learned_by_pokemon.length; k++){
            learned_by_pokemons.push(response.data.learned_by_pokemon[k].name)
        }
        // pass
        if (learned_by_pokemons.includes(current_poke)){move_dict[current_poke].pass.push(curr_move)}
        // fail
        else{move_dict[current_poke].fail.push(curr_move)}

    }
    function getPokes(){
        //iterate through all pokemon
        for (let i = 0; i < db_data.length; i++){
            let current_poke = db_data[i].name
            let moves = db_data[i].moves
            move_dict[current_poke] = {pass: [], fail: []}
            //iterate through all moves of pokemon
            for (let j = 0; j < moves.length; j++){
                let curr_move = moves[j]
                //get data on current move
                get_learned_by_pokemon(curr_move, move_dict, current_poke)
            }
        }
    }

    getPokes()
}
```

I've also used an await before the `Axios.get()`
. I'd like to know why move_dict is not filling and I'd like to overcome this problem without using a `setTimeout()`

Comment: use the for await loop in getPokes function
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for-aw

Comment: Page not found?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for-await...of

Comment: You need to `await get_learned_by_pokemon()` and then whoever calls `getPokes()` will either have to use `.then()` or `await` before trying to use the result too.  `move_dict` is filling just fine - you're just trying to access it BEFORE the rest of the code is done executing and done filling it.

Comment: @jfriend00 do you mind turning this into code? `await get_learned_by_pokemon` is pausing the program

Comment: @BuddyBob Of course it is pausing the program - you *want* to pause the program until `move_dict` is filled, no?

Comment: @BuddyBob it's not pausing the program, it's suspending the execution of the function's control flow until the promise is resolved, allowing the rest of the program to run normally. Nothing is paused.

Comment: note that if `db_data` is a very big array (say it contains thousands of different Pokemon), `getPokes` will potentially take a very long time to resolve, which may be what you're seeing @BuddyBob. Since these API requests and how they interact with each other appear to be independent, rather than having a loop with `await` inside it, which runs the requests one after another, you should use `Promise.all` to run them in parallel. This will probably necessitate quite some rewriting of your current code though.

Comment: @Bergi your right. It was my mistake, I didnt realize how much time it would take for the code to process the data. Using Promise.all made it much faster.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like the OP begins with a json file describing pokemons. From the code, it looks like the file contains at least the following...

```
[
  { name: 'nameA', moves: [ 1, 2, 3, ... ] },
  { name: 'nameB', moves: [ 3, 4, 5, ... ] },
  ...
]
```

It looks like there's an api endpoint that takes a move ("id or name") and returns, among other things, a list of pokemons that have "learned" that move.

And it looks like the OP aims to produce a dictionary like this...

```
{
  nameA: { pass: [1, 2, ...], fail: [3, 4, ...] },
  nameB: { pass: [3, 4, ...], fail: [4, 5, ...] },
 ...
}
```

... where the pass and fail arrays moves found in the input file that either are or are not learned moves according to the api.

Since we don't want to call the api redundantly, and since there might be redundant moves in the input file, it 's worthwhile to create an intermediate structure that associates *unique* moves in the input the pokemons who have learned them, like this...

```
{ // key is a move id or name, value is an array of pokemon names
  1 : [ 'nameA', 'nameB', ... ],
  2 : [ 'nameC', 'nameD', ... ],
  ...
}
```

So here's how I'd describe the idea in code (not compiled or tested)...

```
async function get_learned_by_pokemon(move){
  const response = await axios.get(`https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/move/${move}`);
  return response.data.learned_by_pokemon.map(p => p.name);
}

async function move() {
  let db_data = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync('pokes.json', 'utf8'));
  let allMoves = db_data.flat_map(p => p.moves);
  let uniqueMoves = [...new Set(allMoves)];

  // map move ids to pokemons who learned the moves  { moveId: [ 'pokeA', 'pokeB' ...], ...}
  let learnedBy = {}
  for (let move in uniqueMoves) {
    learnedBy[move] = await get_learned_by_pokemon(move);
  }

  // map pokemon names to a pair of arrays indicating if they have learned their moves (pass) or not (fail)
  let move_dict = db_data.reduce((acc, p) => {
    let name = p.name;
    let pass = p.moves.filter(move => learnedBy[move].includes(name));
    let fail = p.moves.filter(move => !learnedBy[move].includes(name));
    acc[name] = { pass, fail };
    return acc;
  }, {});

  return move_dict;
}
```

Comment: This ended up working fine. Thank you!

Comment: @BuddyBob, if this one helped you, award the reward now and close the bounty early. and I suggest you study async-await a bit more since it is pretty important when working over the network/internet ;)

Comment: Yeah my bad, just awarded. Also ill look into this more. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

there are 2 wrong with your code.
1: where do you call getPokes() ?
2: get_learned_by_pokemon is async function so you have to use await if you want to wait for it done

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to include getPokes() (mistake on copying code over). Also doing `await get_learned_by_pokemon(curr_move, move_dict, current_poke)` seems to stop the code. It does not exit but just pauses.